# How return json object instead of string in json.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I want to implement custom json.net serialize method (null value handling, custom ContractResolver etc.), but when I tried with **JsonConvert.SerializeObject()** I always get string in output instead of formatted json object. 
Here is my code:

```
public class Card
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Test")]
        public IHttpActionResult Test()
        {
            var test = new Card()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "test card"
            };

            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            };
            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, settings);

            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
```

It returns 
`"{\r\n  \"Id\": 2,\r\n  \"Name\": \"test card\"\r\n}"`

When I return object (`return Ok(test);`) in api controller I'll get correct formatted json

```
{
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "test card"
}
```

How I can return json object in api controller with custom implementation of serialize?

Comment: `return Json(test)`?

Comment: @UweKeim I cannot do this because I want add custom ContractResolver to json Serialize method

Comment: That is Visual Studio's formatting probably. Test it by printing it to a file or into the console. @UweKeim read the question again. That's not his problem.

Comment: @Mafii I tested it with Postman application

Comment: @mkul look into Ok(). I don't know what it does exactly, but it escapes the string. Do you have the source of the OK function?

Comment: @Mafii it's asp.net method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn308866(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: you might have to try creating an ok result yourself. Don't have any sources atm, maybe someone else can chime in... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was configuration issue. For attach custom serializer options to global web api configuration, just change WebApiConfig as follow:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.S‌​erializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            };
```

And pass object to return line - serialization will be done automatically